# DataSources folder in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer

Is it possible to access to the "DataSources" window in Visual studio in an MVC project? We are trying to use Report Viewer in our MVC project. Tutorials for setting it up use the DataSources window, but I think this is just a WebForms project feature. Can anyone confirm that that is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataSources are not supported (and do not work) in MVC.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that's what I figured

Comment: Care to share what the alternative is?

Comment: There is nothing directly comparable, since MVC discourages doing data access in views.